# Django taking image from Python program

Tags: python, django

I have previously written some python code which takes some information, and presents it into a chart. An example is in the link below.

[image: Example of chart I want to create]

The python program creates the chart, then places the numbers in the chart in the relevent location. There is some randomness as to where they are placed in the smaller squares.

My question is I would like to implement this in Django. Being new to Django, my thought process is I should be calling the Python code, which would create the image from data from the Django database, and then displaying it. I have worked out how to call the code, however there is little information about how to do so on the click of a button. This has made me question if calling the Python code is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Having spent more time looking into this, and struggling with running the Python code from within Django I am thinking that I should draw this using Canvas. I think ultimately this is a better solution, as it can be managed within Django, and I think will run quicker. I will report back once I have looked into this in more detail.

Comment: Just for reference if anyone else is struggling with something similar, I wrote a function to do this in JavaScript using Canvas to draw all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you need a view connected to a url. A template for that url shows the picture. In your view you should create picture from database data (or even better if you want to make it *djangonic* :-) - create a model method for that) and pass that picture's path to template with the context dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question is more around the creation of the picture using python, and how I get that to operate with django. Should I be using Python to create the image, or when using Django should I be doing this some other way? If I am to use Python, is there a way to tell the program to run from a button for example?

Comment: My answer implies exactly the same code for picture creation. Django is Python, the only thing you take care about is to place your code at proper place. A button in your example is in another page template that links to the template from my answer. P.S. I haven't realized, if you're talking about path, you create picture on disk and pass its relative path.

Comment: Thank you, thats great. This indicates I am on the right track to keep on using my python code to create the image. As I am new to this I didn't know if the correct thing would have been to re-write the code in a different language, to make it more easily compatible. I will therefore persevere, and figure out how to start the code from the button. Thanks again for your help.